# Issues with DCE on TYPO3 upgrade

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, tx-dce

I have Upgraded typo3 from 9.5.5 to 10.4.19 and DCE from 2.03.x to 2.6.2

After the DCE upgrade, the Image upload field configuration seems wrongly changed (https://nimb.ws/slTyH8). The images are not in those fields and in Frontend the images are present which is the cache.

I have tried changing the old configuration of DCE to the new one. The field is okay now, But the website is refreshed and old images are gone.

I have more than 200 pages. So impossible to reupload. I have uploaded my backup and now I am at the previous state.

Checked the install tool, Unfortunately, there are no Upgrade wizards present for DCE. How can I make it correct without losing images?

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

It is the change from old image handling to FAL-based referencing images. In former versions of DCE, the filename has been saved in `tt_content.pi_flexform` and there was a predefined/configured path, where this file should be searched. For some time, in TYPO3 files are handled via FAL and so as a relation to an entry of table `sys_file`...

A few weeks ago, a migrated some DCE elements for a customer. Instead of programming an upgrade-wizard, some lines of PHP were used.

### Step 1: Export relevant data

Export the 'uid' of your content elements and filename within your DCE.

For the DCE with UID=2 whre the files field is called "image" this can be done via:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(pi_flexform, '//field[@index="settings.image"]/value') as filename, `uid`
FROM `tt_content`
WHERE CType='dce_dceuid2' AND ExtractValue(pi_flexform, '//field[@index="settings.image"]/value')!='';
```

Export the result as CSV.

### Step 2: Create releation in `sys_file_reference` and update `tt_content`

Now we have to manage the changes to the database:

1. Create FAL-relations between the DCEs and the `sys_file`-entries (in form of `sys_file_reference`-records)
2. Update the `pi_flexform` of existing DCE content elements
3. Update the structure of old-styled DCEs

For these steps, I generated SQL-Queries with a PHP function:

```
function process(string $csv, string $CType, string $fieldName = 'image'): void
{
    foreach (explode(chr(10), $csv) as $line) {
        [$fileName, $uid] = explode(';', $line);
        if ($fileName && $fileName !== '""') {
            $uid = trim($uid);
            echo htmlentities("INSERT INTO sys_file_reference (uid_local, uid_foreign, tablenames, fieldname, table_local) VALUES((SELECT uid FROM sys_file WHERE identifier=\"/_migrated_/pics/" . $fileName . "\"), $uid, 'tt_content', '" . $fieldName . "', 'sys_file');",
                    ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5) . chr(10);
        }
    }
    echo htmlentities('UPDATE tt_content SET pi_flexform=UpdateXML(`pi_flexform`, \'//field[@index="settings.' . $fieldName . '"]/value\', \'<value index=\"vDEF\">1</value>\') WHERE uid=437 AND CType=\'' . $CType . '\' AND ExtractValue(pi_flexform, \'//field[@index="settings.' . $fieldName . '"]/value\')!=\'\';',
            ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5) . chr(10);

    $configuration = '<config>
        <type>inline</type>
        <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
        <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
        <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
        <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
        <foreign_match_fields>
            <fieldname>{$variable}</fieldname>
        </foreign_match_fields>
        <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
        <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
        <overrideChildTca>
            <columns>
                <uid_local>
                    <config>
                        <appearance>
                            <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                            <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                        </appearance>
                    </config>
                </uid_local>
            </columns>
            <types type="array">
                <numIndex index="2">
                    <showitem>--palette--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette</showitem>
                </numIndex>
            </types>
        </overrideChildTca>

        <minitems>0</minitems>
        <maxitems>1</maxitems>

        <appearance>
            <useSortable>1</useSortable>
            <headerThumbnail>
                <field>uid_local</field>
                <width>45c</width>
                <height>45</height>
            </headerThumbnail>

            <enabledControls>
                <info>1</info>
                <dragdrop>1</dragdrop>
                <hide>1</hide>
                <new>0</new>
                <sort>0</sort>
                <delete>1</delete>
            </enabledControls>

            <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
        </appearance>

        <behaviour>
            <allowLanguageSynchronization>1</allowLanguageSynchronization>
        </behaviour>

        <dce_load_schema>1</dce_load_schema>
        <dce_get_fal_objects>1</dce_get_fal_objects>
    </config>
    ';
    echo 'UPDATE tx_dce_domain_model_dcefield SET configuration=\'' . htmlentities($configuration, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5) . '\' WHERE variable=\'' . $fieldName . '\' AND parent_dce=' . str_replace('dce_dceuid', '', $CType) . ';' . chr(10);
}
```

Now, we need to combine the CSV with the code:

```
$csv = 'image_1.jpg;82
typo3_box.jpg;904';
process($csv, 'dce_dceuid2', 'image');
```

This will *not change* anything, but only print out the necessary SQL-queries, which can be reviewed, copied and fired.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for these detailed explanations.

But We found another method to solve. When analyzing the issue, The Old configuration for the image is having field name as`<fieldname>{$bannerimage}</fieldname>` And in the database the *sys_file_reference* table's field name contains the same variable as `'{$bannerimage}`

What we have done to solve the issue is:

Updated the image configuration to the newest conf and then replaced the `<fieldname>{$variable}</fieldname>` to `<fieldname>bannerimage</fieldname>`
The same is done in the DB too. fieldname changed from `{$bannerimage}` to `bannerimage` This fixed all problems without losing the image.