# DCE image don't run after upgrade to TYPO3 v10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, dce

I have upgraded a TYPO3 project from v6 to v10.

Some content of DCE elements aren't working anymore, this is the code there:

TCA:

```
<config>
    <type>group</type>
    <internal_type>db</internal_type>
    <appearance>
       <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
       <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,jpeg,gif,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
    </appearance>
    <allowed>sys_file</allowed>
    <size>1</size>
    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
    <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
    <dce_load_schema>1</dce_load_schema>
    <dce_get_fal_objects>1</dce_get_fal_objects>
</config>
```

Fluid template:

```
 <f:for each="{field.slide}" as="slide">
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="img-holder">
                    <f:image src="uploads/pics/{slide.bild}" alt="{slide.titel}" />
                </div>
```

How can I fix it to make work again, i have even changed the image to FAL but make error too.

Comment: In the migration path, you have to care about the introduction of FAL. Seems to be the same issue as already discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/68827236/6783328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Julian! I have fixed this issue with change:

```
                    <f:image src="uploads/pics/{slide.bild}" alt="{slide.titel}" />
```

to

```
                    <f:image image="{slide.bild.0}" alt="{slide.titel}" />
```